# Arranging divs in the footer

Tags: html, css

I'm practicing my CSS skills and as you can see below, I've managed to get all my main content between header and footer to line up nicely by using margin: auto.

However I am stuck on figuring out how I get a nice layout going within the footer. What I want is:

Mobile view: To have the footer elements stack vertically and in line with the rest of the site content.

Fullscreen (500px+): Have the footer elements line up horizontally and in line with the rest of the site content.

I've tried to use margin: auto like I did with the main content but it doesn't work.

I can't get the elements inside the footer to do anything, I can actually only see the embedded map for some reason I can't understand.

I hope someone can help me out. Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/y40vcw1q/

```
html body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #DCDBF1;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas:
  "header"
  "menu"
  "content"
  "content2"
  "footer"
}

.wrapper > .content, .content2, .footercontent {
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 2;
  max-width: 50%;
}
.header {
  grid-area: header;
  border-bottom: #EFEEFC solid 1px;
}

.header h1 {
text-align: center;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  grid-area: menu;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.menu a {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.menu a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666666;
}
.content {
  grid-area: content;

}

.content2 {
  grid-area: content2;
}
.content img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  border: solid black 1px;
}
.content2 img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  border-top: #EFEEFC solid 1px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  background-color: #E595B3;
  font-size: small;

}



.footer iframe {

  border: 1px solid black;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;

}


@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
  "header header"
  "menu menu"
  "content content2"
  "footer footer"
}
.header h1 {float: right;
padding-right: 50px;}
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">
  <h1>title.</h1>

</div>
<div class="menu">
<div class="menuitem">
<a href="#">about</a>
</div>
<div class="menuitem">
<a href="#">contact</a>
</div>
<div class="menuitem">
<a href="#">cv</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h1>Content</h1>
    <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/nature-quotes-1557340276.jpg?crop=0.666xw:1.00xh;0.168xw,0&resize=640:*" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<h1>Content 2</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<div class="content2">
<h1>Content 3</h1>
  <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/nature-quotes-1557340276.jpg?crop=0.666xw:1.00xh;0.168xw,0&resize=640:*" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<h1>Content 4</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div class="footer">
<div class="footercontent">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d12087.828828834796!2d-74.00234906126316!3d40.7629659216891!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c25850a4606051%3A0x1976b26060ef9a02!2sHell&#39;s%20Kitchen%2C%20New%20York%20City%2C%20New%20York%2C%20USA!5e0!3m2!1sda!2sdk!4v1598647639460!5m2!1sda!2sdk"</iframe>
<h1>About</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>


<h1>Archive</h1>
<ul>
  <li>jan</li>
  <li>feb</li>
  <li>mar</li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to do with the footer divs? how do you want to arrange them? you can create a subgrid within the footer to align items as you want btw. Works the same way as with the normal grid. Just a grid inside a grid = subgrid.

Comment: Hey mate! I tried creating a sub grid like you said and it seems to have gotten me halfway there, but I cannot get the things to line up properly in the footer. Here is a picture of what I would like to happen: https://imgur.com/a/0cU9nRe

I want the two bottom divs to line up underneath About. I gave them all the same code but only About will get in line. Here is a jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/56rfdzwv/ (I took out the embedded map just to make things easier)

What am I not seeing in the code? thanks!